# Image of $G_K\rightarrow GL_n(\mathbb{C}_p)$ for a closed subgroup?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

Given a continuous map $G_K\xrightarrow{f} GL_n(\mathbb{C}_p)$, where $K$ is a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$,$G_K:=G_{\bar{K}/K}$ and $\mathbb{C}_p$ is the $p$ adic complex number field.

Fixed a constant $c>0$, and let $v_p$ be the p adic valuation of $\mathbb{C}_p$ such that $v_p(p)=1$, and for a matrix $A={(a_{i,j})}_{1\leq i,j\leq n}\in GL_n(\mathbb{C}_p)$, we define $v_p(A)=\text{min}\{v_p(a_{i,j})\}$.

Then can we choose a finite extension $L$ of $K$, such that all matrix $A\in f(G_L)$ satisfy $v_p(I-A)\geq c$($I$ is the identity matrix)?

Remark:I have edited my old question which is wrong. Sorry! This is a question used to prove all $p$-adic Galois representation of $G_K$ is overconvergent.

Thanks!

Comment: I assume $G_K$ means $G_K(\bar{K})$.

Comment: Well, $f(G_L)$ contains the identity, and $v_p(1)=0$. So the answer is no.

Comment: Assume $f(g)$ has an eigenvalue which is not in $O_{\Bbb{C}_p}^\times$, what does it mean in term of the continuity ?

Comment: As per pisco's comment, this is wrong as stated. If you change "$c>0$" to "$c\le 0$", one might have more luck, and should use compactness of $G_K$ (I assume, contrary to RghtHndSd's comment, that $G_K$ denotes the absolute Galois group of $K$).

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my question.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg   Yes，$G_K$ is the absolute Galois group of $K$，and I have edited my question which is wrongly written before. But I don’t know how to use the compactness...

Comment: @reuns Thanks！I will think about this qustion again.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg please take a look at my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is correct, can you check :

With the profinite topology any sequence in $G_K=Gal(\overline{K}/K)$ has a convergent subsequence.

Given $r\in \Bbb{Q}_{>0}$ Let $U=GL_n(\Bbb{C}_p)/(I+p^r M_n(O_{\Bbb{C}_p}))$, it is almost a metric space with $$d(A,B) = \inf_{C\in I+p^r M_n(O_{\Bbb{C}_p})} \sup_{ij} |(AB^{-1} C-I)_{ij}|_p$$ $d$ is continuous on $GL_n(\Bbb{C}_p)$. Thus $f$ is continuous $G_K\to U$, ie. any subquence of $f(G_K)$ has a subsequence which is Cauchy for $d$.

If $f(G_K)\subset U$ isn't finite then this won't happen, because $d(A,B)\ne 0 \implies d(A,B) \ge p^{-r}$.

Thus $f(G_K)\subset U$ is finite and $H=f(G_K)\cap I+p^r M_n(O_{\Bbb{C}_p})$ has finite index and $ \overline{K}^{f^{-1}(H)}$ is your finite extension of $K$.

Comment: In your last word，$H$ is a subgroup of finite index in which group？

Comment: Sssss: In $f(G_K)$. -- @reuns, to see that easier, isn't it enough to say that $f(G_K)$ is compact and $H$ is an open subgroup of it (in its subspace topology), hence must be of finite index?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I think you are right，and this solves my question. An important thing here is that any closed subgroup of a profinite group is itself profinite in its subspace topology！